# Drawing frequency distribution of the daily maximum urban heat island intensity as a function of the time of day

Tags: python, frequency-distribution

I am pretty new to python. I am currently working with urban heat island intensity. The first 10 rows of the 3-hourly uhi intensity data is as follows,

```
uhii = array([[ 1.9,  1.4,  1. ,  0.6,  1.9,  0.6,  0.5,  2. ],
              [-2.1, -1.3, -3. ,  1.8,  0.7,  1. ,  0.8,  0. ],
              [ 0.2,  0.4, -1.8,  1.1,  0.2, -0.2,  0.4,  0. ],
              [ 0.5,  0. , -0.2,  1. ,  0.8,  0.1,  3.4, -0.1],
              [ 1.3,  0. ,  0. ,  0.7,  0. ,  0.9, -1. ,  1. ],
              [ 1.4,  1.6,  0.6,  0.4, -0.5,  0.4,  1.9,  0.7],
              [ 0.8,  0.7,  0.5,  1.6,  1.5,  0.9,  1.7,  1. ],
              [ 0.1, -1.6, -0.3,  2.4,  0.9, -0.2,  0.5,  0.4],
              [ 0.2, -1.5, -0.1,  1.1,  0.5,  0.6, -0.2,  0.4],
              [ 1.2,  1.6, -1.2, -0.4, -0.5,  1.2,  0.6,  1.6]])])
```

here, the hours are 3,6,9,12,15,18,21,00 LST, respectively.
I want and array that will give the the number of occurrence of maximum UHII at a certain LST.

For example, in the uhii array, maximum occurs at 3 LST (along column 1) only once, and at 12 LST (along column 4) 4 times, at 21 LST (along column 7) 3 times.

Therefore, if I consider this uhii array, the result I want is

`result = array([1,1,0,4,0,0,3,1])`

I think I need the loop function, but I cant figure out how to write the logical steps that will lead me to the result I want.

The shape of this uhii array is (10,8), but the data I am working with has a shape of (9922,8).

Comment: How do you count how many times maximum occurs? What are the values in table?

Comment: For this array, I manually searched in each row and noted at which column the maximum value is located. In first row, the max is located in column 8; in second row, max is in column 4.

The values in the tables are the uhi intesnity at 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21 and 00 local standard times

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy`. First you need to compute maximum for each row

```
np.max(uhii, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
array([2. , 1.8, 1.1, 3.4, 1.3, 1.9, 1.7, 2.4, 1.1, 1.6])
```

Then check if value is the maximum by:

```
uhii == np.max(uhii, axis=1)[np.newaxis, :].T
```

Result:

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

And finally compute sum for each column:

```
np.sum(uhii == np.max(uhii, axis=1)[np.newaxis, :].T, axis=0)
```

Result:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 2])
```